# Iterative modification of a Drupal View

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

Currently I have a view with an exposed form to input a numeric param used in a views filter (a distance, used in proximity search). I would like to modify this system to no longer be exposed, but to start at e.g. 10 (miles) and if the view result doesn't contain enough of one kind of node, repeat the view with a larger search distance until I get the result I want, then render the view.

This is Views 2, location, Drupal 6.

Seems like hook_views_pre_render(&$view) is the place to put my code to check on what has been returned by the view, and alter the view accordingly, but I don't know if or how I should call the view again from the top with the modified $view.

UPDATE: Looks like in hook_views_pre_render, if a pager is used, you only get the nodes that are displaying on the current page. I need to be able to see the entire set and reorder it. Or at least if there is no node of type A be able to look down the list and promote one of A into the current page.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to order the results by distance, ascending, then limit the output to ## results. (The SQL should show `ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT ##`)

You can use granularity with the ordering if you *really* want to emulate your description but this seems to be what you are looking for and will be a lot quicker on the engine too.

Comment: Ok, except for the "if the result doesn't contain enough of one kind of node" part. There are 2 flavors of node, A and B, in the search. The results MUST contain a minimum number of A, irrespective of distance. These get floated to the top (first ORDER BY clause). I could e.g. search out to 250 miles and be sure to get both A and B, and then limit 20. But with ORDER BY A first, limit 20 might be ALL A, which might be unacceptable. Or if I search to 25 miles, limit 20 might contain NO A or less than the required A. In practice 250 might serve for idaho, 25 for NYC, but not the reverse.

Comment: What is meant by "granularity with the ordering?" I can take the results of the view and e.g. move up just the first 6 of type A, then pass the view to the renderer?

Comment: Granularity is like when you orderr by distance just do that or order in blocks of 10 miles or so. For what you are asking you will probably need to custom-build a query. Using the `UNION` command you can just run both of the queries and order afterwards, but I'm not sure how to run this in a view.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of very custom request, I'd probably simply make a small module with a page that took everything from input boxes as arguments instead of filters.  I'd grab the query from the views interface (so I didn't have to figure it out myself) and change it into a SELECT COUNT(*) type query, and then write some simple code in a loop - checking the result, and if it's suitably large, exiting the loop and then using those parameters for building the view.  This should save you a lot of time compared to trying to figure out how to do it with all the various options in the views builder widgets.

Comment: The location module's proximity search does the heavy lifting of figuring out what nodes are within my specified radius, so I think this is dependent on views and location. There is nothing more to do in the Views builder UI. What I have returns the nodes, closest first. Now I need to prioritize some "preferred" nodes. Actually the big problem is the pager (required). if its a single array in $view->result in hook_views_pre_render, I could reorder it as needed and put it back into $view->result. But in _pre_render its only the nodes in the current page in ->result.

Comment: So it sounds like some work in the order category, either adding another item in the Views UI for "order" or doing the difficult task of rewriting the sql for the Views query (this can get complicated).